# Logging out with Firebase and Node.JS

Tags: node.js, firebase, logout, firebase-authentication

I wanted to provide a Node.JS Express route wrapper for users who needed to logout and didn't have JavaScript enabled on the front-end. `DB` is my reference to my Firebase:

```
router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    DB.unauth();
    res.redirect(302, '/');
});
```

When I try to logout this way having been logged in, I get the following error:

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

The [documentation for Firebase.unauth()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/unauth.html) is pretty light, but calling it in a route (with or without the `res.redirect`) causes the error. Does anyone have a suggestion or workaround for this issue?

Comment: Is `DB` a pure reference to Firebase here? To counter comments below, `ref.unauth()` does not set response headers in Node, unless you've wrapped the method to do so.

Comment: It's also not clear if a new Firebase client connection is being created for each user request coming into your app. Sharing the connection would have security implications, not to mention possible race conditions with multiple end-users authenticating and de-authenticating the same channel.

Comment: Yes: `var DB = new Firebase('https://MY_FIREBASE.firebaseio.com');` is a declaration up at the top of my apis.js file. It's used by not only logout, but login, register, etc. This shouldn't suffer from Race/Security issues should it? Is there a better way to do this in Node?

Comment: I'm happy to help - reach out to me at rob at firebase.com and we can talk through specifically what you're trying to do and how to best do it. =)

Answer (score 1):

So i was running into the same problem. For me it was that i was using the  asynchronous authDataCallback function.
Apparently onAuth sets your headers so when you try to go to /logout your headers are set and the redirect will fail. So what i did is i switch the authDataCallback 
that i had checking for login states to:

```
var authData = ref.getAuth();

if (authData) {
console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + + authData.provider);
} else {
console.log("User is logged out");
}
```

then my route for log out work flawlessly.

```
app.get('/logout', function(req , res){
   ref.unauth();
   res.redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that error is being thrown on the redirect - you can't headers once the body has been sent. Maybe try:

```
response.writeHead(302, { Location: '/' });
response.end();
```

If that doesn't work, I'd put money on that `.unauth()` is actually setting headers, and if it is, you'll probably need to use the ol' `<noscript>` tag.

All of this said though: you're building an app that uses JavaScript to integrate with Firebase on the back end. Why build a modern web-app that (presumably) relies heavily on JavaScript only to support logging out users when they don't support it? Could they even log in in the first place?

Comment: `DB.unauth()` is indeed setting headers it seems, because as I mentioned in the original post, the error occurs whether or not I use the redirect.

As for app architecture, the user management side of things will rely on JS but browsing the app (both auth'd and non-auth'd users) for files and things will not require JavaScript to maximize availability. Though you bring up an excellent point! If JavaScript is required for user management,  do I need to worry about non-JS users trying to login?  I'll chew on this!

Thanks for the reply, remus !

Comment: Ok - also, keep in mind that _server-side_ JavaScript is entirely different from client-side. `DB.unauth()` is performing the session invalidation that a server would normally perform, and the responses are transmitted by HTTP. In that respect, even with JavaScript disabled, I suspect the client will still be logged out.

Comment: I'm actually quite the front-end wizard so I'm aware of the differences :). Just playing around with Node.JS and Firebase for fun. The Firebase API is supposed to be isomorphic but it's fringe cases like this where I suspect there's bugs since it's primarily used on the front-end exclusively whereas I use it on both. The documentation doesn't mention anything about whether or not `unauth()` is asynchronous or if it has a callback (it does). I was really hoping it'd be super simple to create a logout route that's a one stop shop for eliminating the user session; whether JavaScript is on or off.

Comment: Ahh good stuff. Well... you could just disable .js and see what happens!